# download clearcase plugin in eclipse 2020-03

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, clearcase, cleartool, eclipse-2020-03

I am using eclipse 4.15 (2020-03) and clearcase 8.0.1. I want to download clearcase plugin in eclipse that is supported by this version of eclipse. I tried from https://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipse-ccase/ and https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/306535 but nothing seems to be working.

I couldn't find anything in eclipse marketplace either.
Can someone suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

The [page you mention](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/306535) includes:

1. The ClearTeam Explorer (CTE) is now the preferred ClearCase integration with Eclipse
2. The SCM adapter is not compatible with Eclipse Luna and install will fail.

Regarding point 2, you are using a much more recent Eclipse than Luna.

And point 1 points to "[About Rational ClearCase SCM Adapter in Rational ClearCase version 8.0](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/470599)"

You can see the [CTE plugin used here](http://www.cccqcommunity.com/blogs/clearteam-explorer-adding-eclipse-projects-to-clearcase-source-control), but without indication it would be compatible with recent versions of Eclipse.
And it does not seem available on Eclipse Marketplace.

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of Eclipse currently supported with ClearCase is 4.11, and that requires ClearCase 9.0.1.9. You could try that version with Eclipse 4.15, but no guarantees. There is no 8.0.1.x version that supports that version of Eclipse as ClearCase 8.0.1 support ended over 2 years ago.

ClearCase 8.0.1 EOL: https://www.ibm.com/support/lifecycle/#/details?q45=D120959J76799J93

IBM Software Product Compatibility Reports: https://www.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity/softwareReqsForProduct.html